# Obtaining columns values only if date > today

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query where i need to get values in 4 columns but only if the date is greater than today from a 5th column.   I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
Select  
(case when clientplans.END_DATE < convert(date,getdate(,101) then '') else insplans.Desc_upper as PLAN NAME,
(case when clientplans.END_DATE < convert(date,getdate(,112) then '') else insplans.ID_NO,
(case when clientplans.END_DATE < convert(date,getdate(,112) then '') else insplans.cert_NO,
```

I have converted the date on the end date as follows:
    convert (varchar,clientplans.END_DATE,112) as POLICY_EXP_DATE,

does it matter that I do the conversion of the end date later in the query?   the clientplans.end_date has to be inserted into the results in a certain order which happens to be after the description, id and cert number.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this does what you want:

```
Select (case when cp.END_DATE > cast(getdate() as date) then insplans.Desc_upper end) as PLAN_NAME,
       (case when cp.END_DATE > cast(getdate() as date) then insplans.ID_NO end) as ID_NO,
       (case when cp.END_DATE > cast(getdate() as date) then insplans.cert_NO END) as cert_NO
from clientplans cp . . .
```

Note the following:

- This table uses table aliases (`cp` for `clientplans`), so the query is easier to write and to read.
- It uses `cast()` to a `date` to just get the date.
- Non-matching rows are given a `NULL` value instead of `''`.  That usually makes more sense.

EDIT:

Of course, you can use `''`, if you like:

```
Select (case when cp.END_DATE > cast(getdate() as date) then insplans.Desc_upper else '' end) as PLAN_NAME,
       (case when cp.END_DATE > cast(getdate() as date) then insplans.ID_NO else '' end) as ID_NO,
       (case when cp.END_DATE > cast(getdate() as date) then insplans.cert_NO else '' end) as cert_NO,
       (case when cp.END_DATE > cast(getdate() as date)
             then convert(varchar(255), cp.StartDate, 121) else ''
        end) as StartDate
from clientplans cp . . .
```

Comment: That worked perfectly.   I have to have '' in the results as my interface won't accept NULL.   That just leaves me the expiration date which I don't need if its greater than today.

Comment: I tried using the same statement but its not working  (case when clientplans.END_DATE > cast(getdate() as date) then '' else convert (varchar,clientplans.START_DATE,112) as POLICY_EFF_DATE,

Comment: @RobertIngrim . . . You should always have a length when using `varchar()` in SQL Server, but that is probably not the problem.  Perhaps the problem is the length of the field returned by a `case`.  I always try to put the actual value first, with constant values later, so SQL Server is sure to pick up the type that I really want.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the start of today: `DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)`

For example:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

And for yours...

```
Select  
(case when clientplans.END_DATE > DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0) then '') else insplans.Desc_upper as PLAN NAME,
(case when clientplans.END_DATE > DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0) then '') else insplans.ID_NO,
(case when clientplans.END_DATE > DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0) then '') else insplans.cert_NO,
```

Answer (score 0):

i think proper casting is required So I Used Here `CAST(Field as DATE)` and 
in Your Query `getdate(,101)` is wrong syntax

```
Select  
(case when CAST(clientplans.END_DATE as date) < CAST(getdate() as date) then '')
 else insplans.Desc_upper as PLAN NAME,
(case when CAST(clientplans.END_DATE as date) <  CAST(getdate() as date) then '')
 else insplans.ID_NO,
(case when CAST(clientplans.END_DATE as date) <  CAST(getdate() as date) then '')
 else insplans.cert_NO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cursor on the 5th column

and check @cursor_date> is greater than today.

Only then will get the rest of the 4 columns.